# Android app cannot receive GCM message while another service running?

Tags: java, android, android-service, google-cloud-messaging

I have an Android app that receives a set of coordinates through gcm.

There is nothing wrong with the app. I can receive the coordinates whenever they are changed (I have set a webapp to send the coordinates if they are changed).

I also have another service running that periodically checks for the coordinates of the device using `Context.LOCATION_SERVICE`. This works fine too. This service (when I start it), records the current location of the device and saves it to the database.

My problem is that when I start the location service on the Android app and then go to my other app (webapp) and change the locations (add/remove), they cannot be received by the device. I have to stop the location service (on the device) and then change the locations (so they are sent to the device through gcm) and then the device receives them immediately.

I'm not sure if this is a code problem (I think it is rather a restriction by gcm or android) but if I'm wrong, then tell me if you need to see the code.

Comment: I am assuming no error is thrown by both the webapp and the GCM client app. Add a Log call to your GCM app's BroadcastReceiver. With the other service enabled, see if the BroadcastReceiver gets called whenever you send GCM messages from your webapp.

Comment: I think my problem was that I was using different database connections. I use a singleton class to access the database now. Your suggestion of adding a log to the receiver made me realize that I hadn't done that in a class. Thanks.